# Auto add Opportunity owner in to the account team using trigger?

Tags: trigger

I am trying to add the owner of any new opportunity to the account team of the related opportunity account through the use of a trigger.For example if an opportunity is created and Martin is the opportunity owner, add Martin to the accountteam for the account related to the opportunity. Below is my attempt at the trigger.

## My Code:

```
trigger aINS_populateOpportyOwnerOnActTeam on Opportunity (after insert) {

/*
* Variables used in this trigger
*/
Map<Id, User>  userMap;    //Map to store User records to get the Owner's 
List<Id> userList = new List<Id>();
Set<Id> opptyIdToAccountId = new Set<Id>(); 
Set<Id> oppOwnerId= new Set<Id>();
List<AccountTeamMember> toBeInsertedAcctMbrList = new List<AccountTeamMember>(); // List of Account team members to be inserted
Id currentOppOwner;

for(Opportunity opp : Trigger.new){
    if(opp.AccountId != null){

        opptyIdToAccountId.add(opp.AccountId );
        oppOwnerId.add(opp.OwnerId);
        System.debug('#####opptyIdToAccountId'+opptyIdToAccountId);
        System.debug('#####oppOwnerId'+oppOwnerId);

    }
}

List<AccountTeamMember> lstTeam = [SELECT Id, AccountId, UserId, User.Name, TeamMemberRole
                                    FROM AccountTeamMember
                                    WHERE AccountId IN :opptyIdToAccountId AND UserId IN : oppOwnerId];

System.debug('#####lstTeam'+lstTeam);

//Get the Manager of Opp Owner
If(oppOwnerId.size()> 0){
    userMap = new Map<Id,User>([ SELECT Id, IsActive, UserRole.Name FROM User WHERE Id IN : oppOwnerId]);
    System.debug('#####userMap'+userMap);
}

for(Opportunity oppty : Trigger.new) {
    currentOppOwner = oppty.OwnerId;    
    System.debug('#####currentOppOwner'+currentOppOwner);
    if(Trigger.isInsert && lstTeam.Isempty()){ 

        AccountTeamMember newATM = new AccountTeamMember();
        System.debug('#####newATM'+newATM);
        newATM.AccountId = oppty.AccountId;
        newATM.UserId = currentOppOwner; 
        newATM.TeamMemberRole = userMap.get(oppty.OwnerId).UserRole.Name;
        toBeInsertedAcctMbrList.add(newATM);
        System.debug('#####toBeInsertedAcctMbrList'+toBeInsertedAcctMbrList);

    }
}
insert toBeInsertedAcctMbrList;    
}
```

Comment: Hey Rahul, it wouldn't help your learning if we just wrote the entire trigger for you. However to achieve what yor are trying to do, here are a few steps to help you: 1.create a trigger on the opportunity object. 2.get the owner name (owner field is a reference field so you can do a "owner.name") and accountid from the trigger.new. 3. Use these info to create and add (insert)  a new accountTeamMember. Here's a link on triggers for your reference: https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_triggers_context_variables.htm. Post your code for addtional support.

Comment: Hi..... Thanks for you guidance. I am new to salesforce coding. I did code like this, could you please check it. If any thing changes need, please let me know. Thanks & Regards,Rahul

Comment: I've reopened this since you provided code, can you tell us what the actual problem is with it though?

Comment: LaceySnr. The above code is working fine. 
Thanks!